# When best time to use Stoaryboard iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

I want to develop a new iPhone app and I before developed an app and has been rejected from app store because I was using StoryBoard that is not work in prior iOS 4.3, so I used XIB instead.

Now the minimum version is iOS 4.3 and I want to know is now best time to use StoaryBoard or keep using XIB in my new app?

Hope anyone got my mean. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior` Storyboards only work on devices running iOS 5 above

Comment: you have to create the `xib` files, and you won't be rejected, and forget the Storyboard below iOS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior`. Storyboards only work on devices running iOS 5 above. Since your `deployment target`(minimum supported OS) is 4.3 you have to stick on the Xib file